# open source copycat version of textpad

Tags: open-source, text-editor

I'm a long term Textpad user, which is only available for Windows (wanting to run on Linux). I'm wondering if anyone has ever found an open-source copycat version of it. I know there are plenty of good text editors available that do very similar functions as Textpad, but I would like to use one that looks pretty close and has the same keyboard shortcuts, or maybe even one that can be configured to use the same shortcuts. I have also tried using wine to emulate Windows, but there were issues.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. What features do you need? What "looks" are you after? Consider some long-time Linux user having your copycat but never saw the "original", how shall they know?